# unwanted block appears over text when div size is

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On our site http://reiner-lemoine-institut.de/ueber-uns/team/kathrin-goldammer/, whenever the window is minimized to a certain size, a blue block appears over part of the text.

I have added a screenshot that specifies the exact place within the code that seems to be affected. I am not an expert in CSS or HTML, so I am hestitant to change the code myself:
[image]

Apparently though, the problem appears when the div.column_attr = exactly 339.833 x 908. Anything below this size or above it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a play around with your CSS and think I found what your problem is.

```
.get_in_touch, .infobox {
     background-color: #0f3b64; 
}
```

if you remove/comment out this background-color your problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the following line:

```
.get_in_touch, .infobox {
    background-color: #0f3b64;
}
```

Change to transparent should solve the problem:

```
.get_in_touch, .infobox {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Your theme has a *custom.css* file to put your custom styles in it and is located at: `css/custom.css` so try to add the above code there.

Answer (score 0):

I have a answer for your question. The following class has a background color in your css file. You can remove thet color if not required in the website.

```
.get_in_touch, .infobox{background-color: #0f3b64}
```

Or you can use where inline background image is define i.e in infobox

```
.infobox{background-size:cover;}
```

Comment: I think background-size: cover is a better option as color can be used for some other purpose in other page according to the theme. No need to remove the color if required